# JMeter Beanshell listner script sometimes get ignore in non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, gitlab-ci, beanshell

I created JMeter Test and under first "HTTP Request" I created a Beanshell listner script which works fine when using GUI but 8 out of 10 times the script totally get ignored in non-GUI mode.
I am also running these test in Gitlab CI using Docker Image "justb4/jmeter:latest" and Beanshell script also get ignored there. I don't know whats wrong there it is working fine with GUI

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "get ignored" in JMeter world, it either passes or fails, in case of failure you should see the relevant message(s) in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Also be aware that you should not be using Beanshell at all, [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Listener and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, one of Beanshell's disadvantages is that it's being interpreted each time while Groovy scripts can be compiled and cached providing the most optimal performance. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.

Also be informed that we cannot efficiently help without seeing your code and the aforementioned jmeter.log file.

Comment: I just posted a new question with code here, now it is JSR233 too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461468/i-have-jsr233-listener-which-seems-to-be-ignored-in-jmeter-non-gui-mode